# Getting the index of the returned max or min item using max()/min() on a list

Tags: python, list, max, min

I'm using Python's `max` and `min` functions on lists for a minimax algorithm, and I need the index of the value returned by `max()` or `min()`. In other words, I need to know which move produced the max (at a first player's turn) or min (second player) value.

```py
for i in range(9):
    new_board = current_board.new_board_with_move([i / 3, i % 3], player)

    if new_board:
        temp = min_max(new_board, depth + 1, not is_min_level)  
        values.append(temp)

if is_min_level:
    return min(values)
else:
    return max(values)
```

I need to be able to return the actual index of the min or max value, not just the value.

Comment: The builtin `divmod` exists to prevent having to say `[i / 3, i % 3]` much.

Answer (score 607, accepted):

Find the minimum value with [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) then find that value's index with [`.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations):

```py
values.index(min(values))
```

Or the maximum:

```py
values.index(max(values))
```

If your list contains repeats of the minimum or maximum value this will return the index of the first one.

Comment: @KevinGriffin, Note that this gets you only one of possibly several occurrences of the minimum/maximum. This may not be what you want, for example if it's possible to increase your gain the same two ways, but one of them hurts the other player more. I do not know if this is a case you need to consider.

Comment: @Kashyap It's actually O(N), not O(N^2).  In the min case, first min(values) is evaluated, which is O(N), then values.index() is called, which is also O(N).  O(N) + O(N) = O(N).  The argument to index is only evaluated once.  It's equivalent to: `tmp = min(values); return values.index(tmp)`

Comment: @too much php what to do when there is repetition of elements.?

Comment: @ShashiTunga [list].index() returns only the first occurence of something, it is not guaranteed that it is exclusive, the minimum value might not be unique within the list

Comment: @TomKarzes This is true, however it is still (potentially) twice as slow as it needs to be. If the minimum of a list is calculated by doing a linear scan, the index could be calculated in the same way. Ideally, the list should only be scanned once.

Comment: This is the fastest for single value AFAIK.

Comment: The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) states that the `min `is the first smallest element found in the list. Therefore, it is consistent with `index()`, which returns the first element in the list that matches the key. I also find this method to be much more readable than using `itemgetter`.

Comment: This is the fastest way to do it (even for a list with 500,000 elements) on Python 3.11

Answer (score 719):

Say that you have a list `values = [3,6,1,5]`, and need the index of the smallest element, i.e. `index_min = 2` in this case.

Avoid the solution with `itemgetter()` presented in the other answers, and use instead

```
index_min = min(range(len(values)), key=values.__getitem__)
```

because it doesn't require to `import operator` nor to use `enumerate`, and it is always faster(benchmark below) than a solution using `itemgetter()`.

If you are dealing with numpy arrays or can afford `numpy` as a dependency, consider also using

```
import numpy as np
index_min = np.argmin(values)
```

This will be faster than the first solution even if you apply it to a pure Python list if:

- it is larger than a few elements (about 2**4 elements on my machine)
- you can afford the memory copy from a pure list to a `numpy` array

as this benchmark points out:
[image]

I have run the benchmark on my machine with python 2.7 for the two solutions above (blue: pure python, first solution) (red, numpy solution) and for the standard solution based on `itemgetter()` (black, reference solution).
The same benchmark with python 3.5 showed that the methods compare exactly the same of the python 2.7 case presented above

Comment: The complicated one-liner is fast, but it's also hard to understand. Unless your app is too slow, *and* from profiling you know the simple `values.index(max(values))` is too slow, preferring complicated code is [micro-optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/99463/146293).

Comment: I did a little benchmark in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76981491/19123103) that includes `list.index` (because the above benchmark doesn’t include it), which shows that the method using `list.index` is almost twice as fast as this method.

Answer (score 369):

You can find the min/max index and value at the same time if you enumerate the items in the list, but perform min/max on the original values of the list. Like so:

```
import operator
min_index, min_value = min(enumerate(values), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(values), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

This way the list will only be traversed once for min (or max).

Comment: Or use a lambda: `key=lambda p: p[1]`

Comment: `min([(j, i) for i, j in enumerate(values)])` to avoid expensive function calls.

Comment: @tejasvi88 Tested all three methods (for in loop, lambda, and itemgetter) just now for a array of 1000 values with "%timeit", and itemgetter was the fastest, followed by for-in, and lambda in the last place.

Answer (score 155):

Use NumPy's [`np.argmin()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) or [`np.argmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) functions:

```py
import numpy as np
ind = np.argmax(mylist)
```

Comment: In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned.

Answer (score 55):

Turn the array of values into an array of (value,index)-pairs, and take the max/min of that. This returns the largest/smallest index that has the max/min (i.e. pairs are compared by first comparing the value, and then comparing the index if the values are the same).

```py
values = [3, 5, 4, 5]
m, i = max((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(values))
print((m, i))  # (5, 3)
```

Comment: Using this code, `min()` returns the index of the first minimum and `max()` returns the index of the *last* maximum, which could be surprising because it's inconsistent.

Answer (score 30):

I benchmarked the main answers using [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) (a pet project of mine) on Python 3.11 and it turns out that

```py
values.index(min(values))
```

is the fastest (lower is better):

[image]

unless your array is already a numpy array.

---

Code for generating the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import operator
import perfplot


def min_enumerate(a):
    return min(enumerate(a), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

def min_enumerate_itemgetter(a):
    min_index, min_value = min(enumerate(a), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return min_index

def getitem(a):
    return min(range(len(a)), key=a.__getitem__)

def np_argmin(a):
    return np.argmin(a)

def index_min(a):
    return a.index(min(a))


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.rand(n).tolist(),
    kernels=[
        min_enumerate,
        min_enumerate_itemgetter,
        getitem,
        np_argmin,
        index_min,
    ],
    labels = [
        "key=lambda x: x[1]",
        "key=itemgetter(1)",
        "key=.__getitem__",
        "np.argmin()",
        ".index()"
    ],
    xlabel="len(list)",
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(20)],
)
b.show()
```

Answer (score 11):

If you need all the indexes of the minimum (because the minimum might appear more than once in the list):

```py
minval = min(mylist)
ind = [i for i, v in enumerate(mylist) if v == minval]
```

Comment: I really appreciate this answer as it deals with multiple occurences and most of the other answers deal with just one occurence, which is unusable for me. +1

Answer (score 11):

<sup>There are two answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825864/19123103), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44129039/19123103)) that include benchmark but for some reason, neither of them include `list.index()` into their benchmark, even though it was suggested in the accepted answer that was posted at least 2 years before these answers.</sup>

`list.index()` is the fastest option given on this page, including `enumerate` (all versions that involve it), `__getitem__` and `numpy.argmin`.

Moreover, if the list has a non-unique minimum value and you want to get all indices where the minimum value occurs, `list.index` in a while-loop outperforms other options such as numpy and `enumerate` as well. Note that you can limit its search to begin from a particular index by passing the starting point (which is the second argument to `list.index`), which is crucial for performance because we don't want to search from the beginning in every iteration of the while-loop.

```py
# get the index of the minimum value
my_list = [1, 2, 0, 1]
idxmin = my_list.index(min(my_list))
print(idxmin)   # 2


# get all indices where the min value occurs
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 1]
idxmins = []
min_val = min(my_list)
pos = -1
while True:
    try:
        pos = my_list.index(min_val, pos+1)
        #                            ^^^^^   <---- pick up where we left off in the previous iteration
        idxmins.append(pos)
    except ValueError:
        break

print(idxmins)   # [0, 3]
```

The following benchmarks (performed on Python 3.11.4 and numpy 1.25.2) show that `list.index` is almost twice as fast as all other options no matter the length of the list. The left graph also shows that `getitem` performs the same as `enumerate` (and `numpy.argmin`) for long lists, which shows that [gg349](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825864/19123103) and [Nico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44129039/19123103)'s benchmarks are outdated.

The right graph shows that if the minimum value is non-unique and we want to find all indices of the minimum value, then `list.index` in a while loop as outlined above performs so much better than competing options involving `enumerate` or numpy, especially for long lists.

[image: benchmark]

The code used to produce the figure above:

```py
from operator import itemgetter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import perfplot


def enumerate_1(a):
    return min(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1))[0]


def np_argmin_1(a):
    return np.argmin(a)


def getitem(a):
    return min(range(len(a)), key=a.__getitem__)


def list_index_1(a):
    return a.index(min(a))


def enumerate_2(a):
    min_val = min(a)
    return [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v == min_val]


def np_argmin_2(a):
    arr = np.array(a)
    return np.arange(len(a))[arr==arr.min()]


def list_index_2(a):
    result = []
    min_val = min(a)
    pos = -1
    while True:
        try:
            pos = a.index(min_val, pos+1)
            result.append(pos)
        except ValueError:
            break
    return result


kernels_list = [[enumerate_1, list_index_1, np_argmin_1, getitem], 
                [enumerate_2, list_index_2, np_argmin_2]]
n_range = [2**k for k in range(1, 20)]
su = lambda n: list(range(n, 0, -1))
titles = ['Get index of a unique min value', 
          'Get indices of a non-unique min value']
labels = ['enumerate', 'list_index', 'np_argmin', 'getitem']
xlabel = 'List length'


fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 5), facecolor='white', dpi=60)
for ax, ks, t in zip(axs, kernels_list, titles):
    plt.sca(ax)
    perfplot.plot(ks, n_range, su, None, labels, xlabel, t, relative_to=1)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=13)
plt.setp(axs, ylim=(0, 5), yticks=range(1, 6), 
         xlim=(1, 1100000), xscale='log', xticks=[1, 100, 10000, 1000000]);
fig.tight_layout();
fig.savefig('benchmark.png', dpi=60);
```

Comment: I was suspicious that you were putting the minimum element first and that's why it was so fast, but you're not, `.index()` is indeed the fastest way and it's the most concise/clear to boot.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy yeah, I was kind of surprised to see an overcomplicated solution as a top answer based on a benchmark that doesn’t include `.index()`, so wanted to point out that `.index()` is the best way. I know my answer is very new and buried way down but thanks for scrolling all the way here :-)

Comment: it might be better to edit the top answer instead, we'd need to re-write the code to recreate the benchmark graph though (and preferably add it, commented out, into the answer for future reference).

Comment: I updated [the benchmark answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44129039)

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy I don’t think that edit adheres to SO guidelines as it changes the author’s intent. Also makes the main point of my answer their point, which I don’t think is fair.

Comment: The author's intent was to benchmark the answers, he just missed one.

Answer (score 10):

After you get the maximum values, try this:

```
max_val = max(list)
index_max = list.index(max_val)
```

Much simpler than a lot of options.

Comment: Duplicate of [@too much php's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474030)

Answer (score 9):

This is possible using the built-in [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and `max()` functions and the optional `key=` argument of the `max()` function and a simple `lambda` expression:

```
values = [1, 5, 10]
max_index, max_value = max(enumerate(values), key=lambda v: v[1])
# => (2, 10)
```

In the docs for [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) it says that the `key=` argument expects a function like in the [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) function. Also see the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).

It works the same for `min()`. Btw, it returns the first max/min value.

Answer (score 7):

Use a numpy array and the [`argmax()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) function

```py
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.argmax(a)
print(b)  # 2
```

Comment: Duplicate of [@dr.haz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13533657)

Answer (score 7):

Pandas has now got a much more gentle solution, try it:

`df[column].idxmax()`

Answer (score 6):

Say you have a list such as:

```
a = [9,8,7]
```

The following two methods are pretty compact ways to get a tuple with the minimum element and its index. Both take a **similar** time to process. I better like the zip method, but that is my taste.

### zip method

```
element, index = min(list(zip(a, range(len(a)))))

min(list(zip(a, range(len(a)))))
(7, 2)

timeit min(list(zip(a, range(len(a)))))
1.36 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

### enumerate method

```
index, element = min(list(enumerate(a)), key=lambda x:x[1])

min(list(enumerate(a)), key=lambda x:x[1])
(2, 7)

timeit min(list(enumerate(a)), key=lambda x:x[1])
1.45 µs ± 78.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: "zip method" is a duplicate of [@sophist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29100695) and "enumerate method" is a duplicate of [@Simon Hänisch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40302220)

Answer (score 5):

Use numpy module's function numpy.where

```
import numpy as n
x = n.array((3,3,4,7,4,56,65,1))
```

For index of minimum value:

```
idx = n.where(x==x.min())[0]
```

For index of maximum value:

```
idx = n.where(x==x.max())[0]
```

In fact, this function is much more powerful. You can pose all kinds of boolean operations
For index of value between 3 and 60:

```
idx = n.where((x>3)&(x<60))[0]
idx
array([2, 3, 4, 5])
x[idx]
array([ 4,  7,  4, 56])
```

Comment: index in python starts at 0. index returned shall be 6 (for 65), while your code returns 7 (OP's question was "Getting the index ...")

Comment: In the command, I have queried for index of minimum value (here: 1) whose index IS 7.
65 is the maximum value of elements in the array. If you type:
    n.where(x==x.max())[0]
you will get index of max. value which is 65 here. Its index will come out to be 6

Comment: use of numpy: probably prohibited in this application. But if you are going to use numpy, you're much better of just using `argmin()` instead of what you did here.

Comment: Thanks @RBF06 
I will check it out.

Answer (score 5):

You can pass a lambda as the `key=` argument to [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)/[`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
max_index = max(range(len(my_list)), key=lambda index: my_list[index])
```

Comment: Very clean! And unlike the accepted answer, this is **true** O(n), right? I know that O(2n) is considered O(n), but for very large `n` it can be noticeably slower.

Answer (score 4):

Why bother to add indices first and then reverse them? Enumerate() function is just a special case of zip() function usage. Let's use it in appropiate way:

```
my_indexed_list = zip(my_list, range(len(my_list)))

min_value, min_index = min(my_indexed_list)
max_value, max_index = max(my_indexed_list)
```

Comment: Using this code with a list that repeats the min or the max value (eg `my_list = [1, 2, 2]`), `min()` returns the index of the first minimum whereas `max()` returns the index of the *last* maximum, which could be surprising because it's inconsistent.

Answer (score 4):

Simple as that :

```
stuff = [2, 4, 8, 15, 11]

index = stuff.index(max(stuff))
```

Comment: Duplicate of [@too much php's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474030)

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered. This is consistent with other sort-stability preserving tools such as `sorted(iterable, key=keyfunc, reverse=True)[0]`

To get more than just the first encountered, use the sort method.

```
import operator

x = [2, 5, 7, 4, 8, 2, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8, 3, 4, 9, 3, 6, 5, 0, 9, 0]

min = False
max = True

min_val_index = sorted( list(zip(x, range(len(x)))), key = operator.itemgetter(0), reverse = min )

max_val_index = sorted( list(zip(x, range(len(x)))), key = operator.itemgetter(0), reverse = max )


min_val_index[0]
>(0, 17)

max_val_index[0]
>(9, 13)

import ittertools

max_val = max_val_index[0][0]

maxes = [n for n in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0] == max_val, max_val_index)]
```

Comment: [@Burak Bağdatlı's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5667773) is a more efficient way to do this if you just need the minimum or maximum and don't care about the 2nd smallest or largest value, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a following list `my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and we know that if we do `max(my_list)` it will return `10` and `min(my_list)` will return `1`. Now we want to get the index of the maximum or minimum element we can do the following.

```js
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

max_value = max(my_list) # returns 10
max_value_index = my_list.index(max_value) # retuns 9

#to get an index of minimum value

min_value = min(my_list) # returns 1
min_value_index = my_list.index(min_value) # retuns 0
```

Comment: Duplicate of [@too much php's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474030)

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor addition to what has already been said.
`values.index(min(values))` seems to return the smallest index of min. The following gets the largest index:

```
    values.reverse()
    (values.index(min(values)) + len(values) - 1) % len(values)
    values.reverse()
```

The last line can be left out if the side effect of reversing in place does not matter.

To iterate through all occurrences

```
    indices = []
    i = -1
    for _ in range(values.count(min(values))):
      i = values[i + 1:].index(min(values)) + i + 1
      indices.append(i)
```

For the sake of brevity. It is probably a better idea to cache `min(values), values.count(min)` outside the loop.

Comment: `reversed(…)` instead of `….reverse()` is likely preferable as it doesn't mutate and returns a generator anyway. And all occurrences could also be `minv = min(values); indices = [i for i, v in enumerate(values) if v == minv]`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way for finding the indexes with minimal value in a list if you don't want to import additional modules:

```
min_value = min(values)
indexes_with_min_value = [i for i in range(0,len(values)) if values[i] == min_value]
```

Then choose for example the first one:

```
choosen = indexes_with_min_value[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```py
a=[1,55,2,36,35,34,98,0]
max_index=dict(zip(a,range(len(a))))[max(a)]
```

It creates a dictionary from the items in `a` as keys and their indexes as values, thus `dict(zip(a,range(len(a))))[max(a)]` returns the value that corresponds to the key `max(a)` which is the index of the maximum in a. I'm a beginner in python so I don't know about the computational complexity of this solution.

Comment: This is about 3-5 times slower than the right way to do it and uses twice the memory.