# Find key value of python list for use with other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm currently working on a python program which does a number of calculations using 3 different arrays. The values of the array at each key (i.e. `i[1]` is related to `a[1]` which is also related to `q[1]`.

I am trying to find out which value of `q` is highest (I was using python's `q.max()` function), but I don't know how to find out the value of the key for that max value. I.e. if the max is `q[67]` and is equal to `111110029233` how would I get the `[67]` value so that I can use that key to find the corresponding values in the `i` list and in `a` list.

Comment: If the lists' values are related I'd prefer to use something like `l = [(i[0], a[0], q[0]), ..., (i[n], a[n], q[n])]`, then use `max(l, key=lambda x: x[2])` to get the tuple with the highest value of `q`

Comment: This would just set all of the key's to be related for the entire array, correct? Sorry, just making sure I understand

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure I understand your question. This is a different way to structure your data where each tuple in the list contains the corresponding values for `i`, `a` and `q`. You can create this structure using `l = zip(i, a, q)`

Comment: Ultimately I am doing this for a much larger physics equation where `i`, `a`, `q` are pieces in the equations. I need to run the large equation multiple times with different values (`a` and `i`) and store it's response in `q`. I then am trying to find what value of `q` (or answer to the equation was largest) and show what values of `a` and `i` were used to get this value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the index of the returned max or min item using max()/min() on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> q = [1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1]
>>> q.index(max(q))
5
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import operator
max(enumerate(q),key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

`max` will not return the index, to find it you will have to do a loop through the list like so:

```
q = [1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1]

def find_max(li):
    max_item = max(li)
    return (li.index(max_item), max_item)

print find_max(q)
```

You can then use the first element in the returned value to access the related elements in your lists.

Alternatively if you only want the index you can use:

```
q.index(max(q))
```

as answered in [This Stack overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, I had tried to search and didn't see that. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
q = [1,2,3,4,5,100,-1,0]
index = max(enumerate(q), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your ultimate goal is to find the `a` and `i` values that produce the largest `q` value. Currently you're trying to find the index of that maximum `q` so you can use it to access the corresponding values in `i` and `a`, but I think it is more efficient to go about it in a different way.

```
max_q, max_i, max_a = max(zip(q, i, a))
```

This finds the maximum `q`, value, and the corresponding `i` and `a` values. Here's how it works:

First the `zip` function constructs a generator (or list, if you're using Python 2) of tuples of matched values from each of the lists. That is, it yields `(q[0], i[0], a[0])` followed by `(q[1], i[1], a[1])` and so on.

Then the `max` function will compare the tuples, using the first value (from `q`) as the most significant piece. If there is a unique maximum value in `q`, this will be it. If there is a tie for maximum, the code I wrote above will prefer the one with the highest `i` value, and if that is tied, the one with the highest `a` value.

Finally, it unpacks the maximum tuple into `max_q`, `max_i` and `max_a` variables so you can use them individually.