# How to search list of objects for index of minimum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to search through a list of objects for the lowest number present in an attribute of the objects.

This is easy enough using a list comprehension and the `min` function. The issue comes when I want to find the index of the object.

```
class School:
    def __init__(self, name, num_pupils, num_classrooms):
        self.name = name
        self.num_pupils = num_pupils
        self.num_classrooms = num_classrooms

    def students_per_class(self):
        return self.num_pupils / self.num_classrooms

    def show_info(self):
        print(f"{self.name} has {self.students_per_class():.2f} students per class.")

    def string_checker(question):
        valid = False
        while not valid:
            try:
                response = str(input(question))
                if all(character.isalpha() or character.isspace() for character in response):
                    valid = True
                    return response
                else:
                    print("Enter a string containing no numbers of special characters. ")
            except ValueError:
                print("Enter a string containing no numbers of special characters. ")

    def num_checker(question):
        valid = False
        while not valid:
            try:
                response = int(input(question))
                if (response):
                    valid = True
                    return response
                else:
                    print("Enter an integer containing no letters or special characters. ")

        except ValueError:
            print("Enter an integer containing no letters or special characters. ")

    def new_school():
        school_name = string_checker("School Name: ")
        num_pupils = num_checker("Number of Pupils: ")
        num_classrooms = num_checker("Number of Classrooms: ")
        return School(school_name, num_pupils, num_classrooms)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    schools = []
    school = School("Darfield High School", 900, 37)
    schools.append(school)
    school.show_info()

    for i in range(1):
        schools.append(new_school())

    for school in schools:
        school.show_info()

    print(min(school.students_per_class() for school in schools)) 
    # This works fine and prints the value of the lowest number
    print(schools.index(min(school.students_per_class() for school in schools))) 
    # This doesn't work as it tries to find the index of the value returned
    # from the min function as it should.
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16945518/2988730

Comment: Lists and arrays are not the same in Python. You have lists.

Comment: Do you assume the minimum is unique; or return the first such index? or else all such indices, which means the result could be either an integer or list. Or a list with 1+ items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `min`'s `key` argument to search by index:

```
index = min(range(len(schools)), key=lambda i: schools[i].students_per_class())
print(schools[index])
```

A key provides the values that will be compared instead of the actual sequence. Here, my sequence is `range(len(schools))`, which is just the indices of all the elements. But instead of finding the minimum index, I am making it so that we find the minimum of `schools[i].students_per_class()` for each index `i`.

Comment: Could you extrapolate on what the lambda "key" is actually doing. Thank you.

Comment: @Alex. Yes, I can elaborate

Comment: I apologise for my poor use of words. Could you please elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex. I've elaborated

Comment: @Alex. We've all been beginners at some point. If you are willing to make an effort, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to be able to compare, sort, find the min/ max on the items directly you could use the "dunder" methods. These methods allow you to overload built in functions on classes.

For instance if you had a class like this

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value
```

You can then create two instances and compare them directly like this,

```
A = Item(1)
B = Item(2)

print(A < B) # Prints True
```

or if you had a list of items

```
items = [A, B]
```

You can then get the minimum item by going

```
min_item = min(items)
```

or the index of it by going

```
min_item_index = items.index(min(items))
```

although it may be enough to just have a reference to the minimum item.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to iterate through lists while keeping track of indices:

```
min(((i, school.students_per_class()) for i, school in enumerate(schools)), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

`(i, school.students_per_class())` is a tuple and using `key` parameter of `min()`, we ask Python to find minimum of `school.students_per_class()`, which subsequently returns it's index along with it.

Read about lambda [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain what is happening with enumerate and lambda? I have no idea. Thanks again. Edit: Could you put it into my context.

Comment: You need to swap the order of the result tuple or it will always return the first item, whose index is 0.

Comment: @AlexStiles, I have added links to official documentation for further reading on `enumerate` and `lambda`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for [np.argmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) function, if you provide a list as an input it will return the index of the minimal element.

in this case it would be:

```
import numpy as np 
min_ind = np.argmin([school.students_per_class() for school in schools])
print(schools[min_ind])
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tomas Ordonez

Your answer is here:

```
def minInt(instanceList):
    sorted_instanceList = sorted(instanceList, key=lambda instance: instance.int)
    minIndex = instanceList.index(sorted_instanceList[0])
    return minIndex
```

Comment: This assumes the minimum is unique; or else it returns the first such index (not all such indices).