# How to find the maximum of two lists at the same indices

Tags: python, list, max

I am trying to find the maximum point for two different lists at the same index. Example:

```
l1 = [11,4,7,9]
l2 = [2,10,9,6]
```

The result from this example would be that l1 and l2 are both maximized at their third index (where l1 = 7 and l2 = 9).

Is there an existing function that can do this? If not, how would I approach this.

Comment: You mean you want to find the index at which the sum of the corresponding elements of `l1` and `l2` is greatest? `l1` and `l2` are definitely not _"both maximized at their third index"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to better define what you mean/expect as the "both maximized" concept.

For example, the pairs of values could be treated as x,y coordinates in a cartesian plane with the farthest euclidian distance from origin representing the maximized concept:

```
l1 = [11,4,7,9]
l2 = [2,10,9,6]

i = max(range(len(l1)),key=lambda i:l1[i]**2+l2[i]**2)
print(i)
2
```

*This selects the 3rd index but so would the simple sum of values in this particular case.*

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple `argmax` function (as given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945518/finding-the-index-of-the-value-which-is-the-min-or-max-in-python#answer-26726185)):

```
def argmax(iterable):
    return max(enumerate(iterable), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

And call it on the pairwise sums:

```
argmax(map(sum, zip(l1, l2)))
# 2
```

Some docs on the utils:

- [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)
- [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)
- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)