# Find the index of minimum values in given array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to find the index of more than one minimum values that occur in an array. I am pretty known with `np.argmin` but it gives me the index of very first minimum value in a array. For example.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,6,1])    
print np.argmin(a)
```

This gives me 0, instead I am expecting, 0,5,7.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `np.where(a == a.min())`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the index of the returned max or min item using max()/min() on a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,6,1]) 
print np.where(a == a.min())
```

argmin doesn't return a list like you expect it to in this case.

Comment: No, it doesnt. Moreover, you are overwriting a built-in function `min`.

Comment: @BasSwinckels you missed my edit. regular min works fine as you pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe

```
mymin = np.min(a)
min_positions = [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == mymin]
```

It will give [0,5,7].

Comment: No, it doesn't, since you are comparing to the index of the min, which is 0.

Comment: EDITED, use min instead of argmin, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be the easiest way, although it doesn't use any fancy numpy function

```
a       = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,1,6,1])                                        
min_val = a.min()                                                            

print "min_val = {0}".format(min_val)                                        

# Find all of them                                                           
min_idxs = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(a) if val == min_val]              
print "min_idxs = {0}".format(min_idxs)
```