# find the maximum value and its index in an numpy array

Tags: python, opencv

I have an array like:

```
[ [0.0], [0.0020777732133865356], [0.0013433878775686026], [0.00021494206157512963], [8.955918747233227e-05], [0.0], [0.0], [1.7911837858264334e-05], [0.0], [1.7911837858264334e-05], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0007702090078964829], [0.02625875361263752], [0.13904960453510284], [0.30124127864837646], [0.30514606833457947], [0.4224506914615631], [0.45712801814079285], [0.5807734131813049], [0.5874545574188232], [0.695248007774353], [0.18126779794692993], [0.11689265072345734], [0.07207723706960678], [0.06512743979692459], [0.06016586348414421], [0.04363323748111725], [0.030235182493925095], [0.03095165640115738], [0.028963441029191017], [0.03578785061836243], [0.029267942532896996]]
```

I want to find the maximum value and its index.
I have searched for this but none match my question.
is there any solutions?
Thanks.

Comment: How about having a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list)

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with

```
In [6]: ind = np.argmax(a)

In [7]: a[ind]
Out[7]: array([ 0.69524801])
```

Since you have a two-dimensional array, you might prefer:

```
In [9]: a[ind][0]
Out[9]: 0.69524800777435303
```

Answer (score 1):

In case there can be more than one max value:

```
In [16]: arr = np.array([1,4,3,2,5,6,3,5,7,4,7,1,4,7,3])
In [17]: np.max(arr)
Out[17]: 7
In [18]: np.where(arr == np.max(arr))
Out[18]: (array([ 8, 10, 13]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a nested list. So here are the steps.

create a newlist
add all the eelments to this list 
sort the list and you get maximum value and get the index

here a is your array

```
myList = [ ]
for mylist in a:  
    print mylist[0]
    myList.append(mylist[0])
```

## copy the list

```
import copy
sortedList = copy.copy(myList)
sortedList.sort()
sortedList.reverse()
# to Get the 5 maximum values from the list
for i in range(0,4):
    print sortedList[i]
    print myList.index(sortedList[i]
```

Comment: You do not need to sort the entire list for just getting the max element. This is O(nlogn) complexity instead of just O(n). Also, I don't see how you get the index with this approach, except by storing the index together with the value and then getting the max of that tuple.

Comment: I did it but the error is:AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: I also want to extract 5 max values with their respective indexes.

Comment: @user5538206 When you say "5 max values", do you mean the 5 highest values, or 5 values that all happen to be the same max value?

Comment: I mean 5 highest values:)