# What is faster? minimum of list then index of minimum, vs iterating through list

Tags: python, list, min

I am using python and I have a list of lists, say list1 where each inner list has 2 elements.
I have a second list, say list2. The ith element of list1 corresponds to the ith element of list2.

Is it faster to find:

```
lowest = min(list1, key=lambda x: x[1])
index = list1.index(lowest)
correspondingLowest = list2[index]
```

Or is it faster to:

```
lowest = list1[0]
lowestValue = sys.maxint
saveIndex = 0
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i][1] < lowestValue:
        lowest = i
        saveIndex=i
correspondingLowest = list2[saveIndex]
```

I don't know how the inbuilt functions min(list) and list.index work, but I assume they both involve iterating over the entire list, in the case of min, and up to the index'th element in the case of .index. Whereas in the second option, it will only iterate through the list once.

My list1 and list2 will have at least 100000 elements in them so any differences will be noticeable. I expect there are other, possibly faster options out there too?

Note, I need to find the values for lowest and correspondingLowest, I am not just finding lowest so that I can find correspondingLowest.

Comment: You should try to time it. Also, I think numpy has a idxmin() function, that precisely returns the index of the minimum value of its array. I don't know if using numpy array instead of lists is applicable in your case.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2474238/2301450

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generate indices using the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and use the `key` argument function for `min()` to make sure it finds the  smallest list value from the resulting (index, element) tuples:

```
min_index, min_value = min(enumerate(list1), key=lambda ie: ie[1][1])
```

Finding the minimum then looking up the index has to scan the list twice, and the `min()` loop, implemented in C, is going to beat a Python loop hands-down.

If all you are doing is map indices from one list to the other, you could also just *zip* the two lists:

```
min1, min2 = min(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda ee: e[0][1])
```

This picks the minimum value in `list1`, and returns that value *together with the corresponding value in `list2`*. If this is Python 2, use the [`future_builtins.zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html#future_builtins.zip) for future compatibility and avoiding building the whole paired list in memory:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    from future_builtins import zip
except ImportError:
    # Python 3, it is built-in
    pass
```