# How to colour maximum and minimum of each bar in bar graph in python?

Tags: python, arrays, graph

I am trying write a function that will draw the bar graph when given the array of each length of the bar. When I run the function with given array, it will draw the bar graph and all of the bars are coloured with blue colour. I have finished that part and 
below is the code for that part.
The problem I am having is that I am stuck with figuring out a way to colour differently to maximum and minimum bar in that graph.

```
def drawgraph2(volumes):
   maxLength = maxValue2(volumes)
   pict = makeEmptyPicture(700,(700/4)*3)
   w = getWidth(pict)
   h = getHeight(pict)
   grey = makeColor(220,220,220)

   x = 10
   for n in range (0, len(volumes)):
     addRectFilled(pict, x+100, (h-(maxLength/10))-volumes[n], 30, volumes[n], blue)
     x = x+50
   repaint(pict)

def maxValue2(trainsList):
  max = trainsList[0]
  for n in range(1, len(trainsList)):
    if trainsList[n]>max:
       max = trainsList[n]
    return max
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to get ids of max and min ([How to get min and max ids of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list)).

```
minId = volumes.index(min(volumes))
maxId = volumes.index(max(volumes))
```

Then you can fill a vector with your default color using list comprehension.

```
myColourList = ["blue" for i in range(len(volumes))]
```

And modify it thanks to your indexes;

```
myColourList[minId] = "red"
myColourList[maxId] = "green"
```

Finally in your loop, you can replace the line:

```
addRectFilled(pict, x+100, (h-(maxLength/10))-volumes[n], 30, volumes[n], blue)
```

By:

```
addRectFilled(pict, x+100, (h-(maxLength/10))-volumes[n], 30, volumes[n], myColourList[n])
```