# Python 2 Finding the index of minimum value in a subarray

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm new to programming and have just started out with learning algorithms. The problem I'm trying to solve is from the Khan Academy algorithms course (it's in JavaScript but I'm going through it in Python) and it asks for me to find the index of the minimum value in a subarray.

Specifically, the task is as follows : 
Finish writing the function indexOfMinimum, which takes an array and a number startIndex, and returns the index of the smallest value that occurs with index startIndex or greater. If this smallest value occurs more than once in this range, then return the index of the leftmost occurrence within this range.

I've been searching the web for an answer to this problem for about a week now and haven't managed to find any resources that address it in Python 2. I would greatly appreciate if somebody could help me out on this. 
Edit: after reading some of your responses, I have the following: (it works for me but if somebody sees something wrong with it, please comment below)

```
def indexOfMinimum(lst,index):      
    sublist = lst[index:]  
    for minValue in lst:  
        minIndex = sublist.index(min(sublist))  
        return minIndex  
print indexOfMinimum([2,4,6,8,1,3,5,0,7,9], 4)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list. First answer to "python index of minimum value in list" in Google. Use a "list slice" for your other requirement to start mid way through the list. `index` by default will return the leftmost occurrence if it appears multiple times.

Comment: Look here: http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/05/21/computer-algorithms-minimum-and-maximum/

Comment: So where is your code ?

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll read through the links you posted and see if it helps :) 

t.m.adam I didn't have anything worth posting tbh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will take three Python facilities: a list slice, and the methods **min** and **index**.  Using your start index, set **sub_list** to be the required slice of the given list.  Apply **min** to **sublist**, getting the minimum value of the list.  Finally, use **sublist.index** on that min value to get the index of the left-most appearance.

Is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: I'm going to try it out a bit, and read over what some of the other people that commented wrote and then I'll get back to you. The thing that's confusing me is that it's asking for the index of the minimum in the subarray. I know how to find the index of the minimum in an array but I'm really struggling to wrap my head around this. I know it's probably really simple so I'm hoping I'll get there soon.

Comment: `def indexOfMinimum(lst,index):`
    `slice = lst[lst[index]:len(lst)]`
    `sublist = slice`
   `for minValue in lst:`
        `return sublist.index(min(sublist))`
`print indexOfMinimum([2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9], 2)`

Something like this? @Prune
idk how to type it properly in this forum sorry.. the indentation is correct in the original

Comment: (1) Don't worry; you can't format code in a comment, so you did fine.  (2) Yes, that should *almost* work.  You can do a little better with the **slice = lst[index: ]**  You can omit the ending index.

Comment: Thanks so much, I edited my initial question with the code last night. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to set a variable (here "result") to the first (you could also start from right to left) element of your array and go through your array comparing to every element. If the element result is being compared to is smaller, set result to be equal to it.

To get you started, here's a simple (naive) way to solve it:

```html
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = array[0]
for i in array:
  if result > i:
    result = i
    i += 1;
print(result)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this out and some other things and see if it clears things up!

Comment: I've tried running this but it seems to only be printing the value 1.. also, I need the index of the minimum of a subarray starting from a given index whereas you're referring to an array. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, you can just change the array. I give this one as an example.

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of ways to this, here's one:

```
def indexOfMinimum(lst,index):
smallest=lst[index] #assuming index is within range
smallestIndex=index
while index<len(lst):
    if lst[index]<smallest:
        smallest=lst[index]
        smallestIndex=index
    index+=1
return smallestIndex
```

Comment: I'll try run this and see what happens.. I had something similar written up a few days ago but it kept only returning the index I was initially typing into the function (maybe I had the indentation wrong).