# How to check if an integer at a given location is greater than every other integer within that list?

Tags: python

I am attempting to see if an integer at a given location is greater than every other integer within that list. For example:

```
values = [2,5,3,1,6]
if values[0] < all other integers
    print something
```

Keep in mind, I need to see if that specific index is less than all of the other indexes in the list, therefore, using something like `min(values)` will not work.  A list such as

```
values = [2,5,3,1,6,1]
```

has *no* single minimum value; any given index should return `False`.

Comment: [Loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)?

Comment: "using something like min(values) will not work." ? why not ? `if values[0] <= min(values):...`

Comment: [Getting the index of the returned max or min item using max()/min() on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2474015/953482) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to assert if any one item in the list meets a condition. Just skip the one entry in question like so:

```
def f(li, idx):
    return any(e>li[idx] for i, e in enumerate(li) if i!=idx)   

>>> f([2,5,3,1,6], 0)
True
>>> f([2,5,3,1,6], 4)
False
```

You can reverse `<` to `>` or whatever to fit your use. (Or add a `not`)

If you want to assert that the given index has a relationship with all other list elements, use [all](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
def f2(li, idx):
    return all(e>li[idx] for i, e in enumerate(li) if i!=idx)

>>> f2([2,5,3,1,6,1], 3)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `all` operator to iterate over a sequence.  In this case, you also have to eliminate checking against self.  The boolean expression would be:

```
>>> values = [2,5,3,1,6]
>>> given_loc = 0

>>> all ([values[given_loc] < values[i] \
        for i in range(len(values)) \
            if i != given_loc])
False
>>> given_loc = 3
>>> all ([values[given_loc] < values[i] for i in range(len(values)) if i != given_loc])
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function like this:

```
values = [2,5,3,1,6]
loc = 4
if not any((values[i] > values[loc]) for i in range(len(values)) if i != loc):
    print('something')
```