# Computing and removing the two smallest quantities in a list

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have a program for a pet shop. I have a nested list where each column corresponds to an animal and the numbers in the columns show the number of that animal in each cage:

```
cages=[[1,5,2,3],[2,1,1,5],[0,4,1,1]]
```

So I have a list l containing 4 variables which contain the number of each animal, calculated with sum:

```
    dogs=sum(i[0] for i in cages)
    hamsters=sum(i[1] for i in cages)
    cats=sum(i[2] for i in cages)
    birds=sum(i[3] for i in cages)

    l=[dogs,hamsters,cats,birds]
```

So the variables are equal to: dogs=3, hamsters=10, cats=4, birds=9

The scenario is that a customer wants to buy all of one type of animal, for example they want to buy all of birds or all of hamsters, but we don't know which one of the four animals they will buy. The only thing I know it that they will buy two of the animals smallest in numbers (that will be dogs and cats). I need to update the list l so the program deletes the animal from the list since the animal is not in the shop now. Here is how I did it:

```
smallest=[]
for animal in l:
  smallest.append(min(l))
  break

for animal in smallest:
  while len(l)>3:
    if animal==dogs:
        l=[hamsters,cats,birds]

    elif animal==hamsters:
        l=[dogs,cats,birds]

    elif animal==cats:
        l=[dogs,hamsters,birds]

    elif animal==birds:
        l=[dogs,hamsters,cats]
```

Then I empty smallest to find the new smallest animal:

```
smallest.clear()
```

Then I try to do the same thing for the second smallest animal:

```
smallest=[]
for animal in l:
    smallest.append(min(l))
    break

for animal in smallest:
    while len(l)>2:
```

This is where I get stuck. Since I'm not supposed to know which animal was bought at first (the numbers in cages can vary each time I run the program because the pet store sells and buys animals all the time), I don't know how to define the l now. I will now need multiple if statements for example:

```
if animal(deleted before)==dogs and animal(being deleted now)==cats:
  l=[hamsters,birds]

elif animal(deleted before)==dogs and animal(being deleted now)==hamsters:
  l=[cats,birds]
```

and so on, and if I am not mistaken I will need four times as many if statements as before. Is there a way to condense this so that I only have four if loops like in the previous bit of code?

Comment: First of all, is this a homework problem? Second of all, what restrictions are there here? For example, are you able to change the structure of the input data?

Comment: No, I am just testing how well I understand python since I recently got a python textbook. And yes, you can change the input data so I cannot manually delete animals from the list

Comment: I can see no reason for the downvote you got. This shows a clear problem and a good amount of effort to solve it on your own. Basically a good question.

Comment: Sounds good. Are you familiar with classes?

Comment: I only know that they are loosely like custom variables and I am not very confident with them, but I am open to leaning new bits of python code. Is there another way of doing it other than classes though?

Comment: Sure. I will discuss a couple of approaches.

Comment: I hope you take the time to read through my answer and let me know if there is anything I could explain better. I did not go into classes at all, mostly just cleaned up your code a lot. Out of curiosity, why did you feel the need to put loops into so many places they don't belong?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will read through it once I am done with some work. As for the loops I guess I didn't understand how to use the min() correctly and now I realize the loop is pretty useless

Comment: You have a long way to go yet but you're on the right track. This is a great example of the kind of beginner question I wish I could see more of: the code is all messed up but you know exactly what you want to do, and are able to articulate it well because you've put a lot of thought into it. The tools will come with practice. Keep it up and happy coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly pinpointed a major conceptual difficulty with your approach. When there is no real labelling between animal type and count besides index in a list, you can't move list elements around, making the computation more complicated.

That being said, there are also a number of things that need to be fixed in your code. I would like to address these issues in detail before showing a solution since your goal seems to be to learn Python better. Starting from the top:

1. The loop in the beginning is pointless and confusing:

   ```
   smallest=[]
   for animal in l:
      smallest.append(min(l))
      break
   ```

   You start iterating over `l`, but never use the variable `animal` in the loop: already a red flag. Then you append `min(l)` to a list and immediately exit the loop. The loop iterates only once and serves no purpose. Neither does the list `smallest`.

   You could rewrite that whole block as `smallest = min(l)`, which would make `smallest` a single `int` object.
2. Item #1 means that there is literally no reason for the following loop (`for animal in smallest:`) either: `smallest` is was a list of one element before, and now it points directly to the element itself.
3. The nested loop (`while len(l)>3:`) is superfluous as well. When you know for a fact that you only want to do an operation once, it should not be in a loop. This obsession with loops is very unhealthy :)
4. The removal of the smallest element removes the mapping from index to animal and vice versa. For example you start with `l[0] == dogs`, `l[1] == hamsters`. That means that if the customer buys all the dogs, you end up with index `0` now representing hamsters instead. You need to find a solution that does not have this problem (shown below).
5. You do *not* need a huge set of `elif` statements to do the selection in the first place. There are much better ways of removing the correct element. The easiest one conceptually is to find the index of the minimum and to just get rid of the element there.

   Computing the index would involve changing `smallest` from holding the smallest value of `l` to the *index* of the smallest value. It could be done something like `smallest_index = min(range(len(l)), key=l.__getitem__)` (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825864/2988730)). This representation basically says, find the smallest index in the list (`range(len(l))`), but based on the value at that index, not the index itself (`key=l.__getitem__` means that the minimum will be computed based on `l[index]` instead of just `index`).
6. The line `smallest.clear()` serves no purpose whatsoever. You reset `smallest` immediately after.

Now on to the actual solution. The main thing to remember when you program is "what am I trying to model/solve here?". When a customer buys all your dogs, does the pet shop lose the ability to sell dogs? Probably not, but there are none in stock at the moment. The way to model that is not to remove the element entirely then but to set it to zero, as you do in a cage. This will fix 90% of your problems. The remaining 10% is just following your goal as directly as possible instead of putting loops everywhere.

Now the first part of your code will look something like this:

```
smallest_index = min(range(len(l)), key=l.__getitem__)
l[smallest_index] = 0
```

That's it. Minimum element removed. This does not immediately fix the problem of how to find the second smallest element since you now have a zero in your list. But what if you never had dogs to begin with? There would be a zero in `l[0]` and we would not be handling it correctly. So we need to write a new version of the search key to get `smallest_index` that checks if the key is non-zero, killing both birds with one stone:

```
def search_key(index):
    return (l[index] == 0), l[index]
indices = range(len(l))

smallest_index = min(indices, key=search_key)
l[smallest_index] = 0
second_smallest_index = min(indices, key=search_key)
l[second_smallest_index] = 0
```

Here's how it works. If your search key is a tuple, the elements of the key will be compared in order. I use that fact here to return a tuple that contains `True` in the first element if and only if the array element is zero. Now `True == 1` and `False == 0` in Python. This means that elements that are zero get pushed to the end of the sort order, and all non-zero elements get considered first. Now, once you set the first smallest animal count to zero, doing the same search again will yield the next smallest *non-zero* count. And as you can see, setting elements to zero instead of shrinking the list means that the indices correspond to the animal type. You may not have any dogs left in the store, but `l[0]` will always be the number of dogs regardless.

If you test this out with your example:

```
labels = ['dogs', 'hamsters', 'cats', 'birds']
cages = [[1, 5, 2, 3],
         [2, 1, 1, 5],
         [0, 4, 1, 1]]
indices = range(len(labels))
l = [sum(cage[index] for cage in cages) for index in indices]

def search_key(index):
    return (l[index] == 0), l[index]

for _ in range(2):
    smallest_index = min(indices, key=search_key)
    print('Customer bought {} {}'.format(l[smallest_index], labels[smallest_index]))
    l[smallest_index] = 0
```

You get:

```
Customer bought 3 dogs
Customer bought 4 cats
```

Notice that I did put the functional code in a loop here. The loop makes sense here: the customer is buying the animal with the smallest non-zero count two times. Both times it is exactly the same operation, and the customer may do it more than twice, making anything other than a loop cumbersome to deal with.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped! I included the if loops so I can do more things with the animal that is about to be deleted. I was thinking on deleting its column so that the cages correspond to the animals remaining and I thought I can only do that with loops. I agree I seem to have an obsession with loops I don't know why

Comment: I was just thinking is there a way of doing it with loops so I can do additional calculations to the variable being deleted? And if yes, how do I go about my initial problem with loops?

Comment: @jane. I think the last part of my answer sort of addresses that already. The print statements are a place holder for whatever you really need to do. If you have something specific in mind, play around with it and if it doesn't work out, ask another question.