# how to find index of min and max value of a int array Python

Tags: python, max, min, enumerate

Hello I want to find the first index of the max and min value of an array of integer.

my code returns all the index in case of duplicate values ...

```
A= [1,1,8,7,5,9,6,9]
def minmaxloc(num_list):
  for i,y in enumerate(num_list):
    if y ==max(num_list) or y==min(num_list):
      print i
minmaxloc(A)
```

output: 
0
1
5
7

what i want : 
(0,5)

thanks for your help.

Comment: `import numpy as np; (np.argmin(A),np.argmax(A))`

Comment: The top answer in the question you were pointed to isn't that great since it sweeps over the array potentially twice. The 2nd answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474238/500207 is better in this regard. Ideally you'd be able to calculate the max and min in a single sweep, but neither Python or Numpy provide a `minmax` :(

Answer (score 2):

```
def minmaxloc(num_list):
    return num_list.index(max(num_list)), num_list.index(min(num_list))

print(minmaxloc(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy's argmin and argmax methods:

```
import numpy as np
def minmaxloc(num_list):
    return np.argmin(num_list), np.argmax(num_list)
A= [1,1,8,7,5,9,6,9]
print(minmaxloc(A))
```

Comment: Thanks for help! It works fine But I want to use enumerate

Comment: Why the downvote though? Can you elaborate why you need enumerate? It seems there is more to the story.