# Find minimum element and its position in list with Nones

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, min

I have a list of numbers and `None`s like this:

```
l = [2., None, 3., 1., None, 2., None, 5.]
```

I want to get the minimum number and its index, while the `None`s should simply be ignored. For the given example, the result would thus be:

```
(1., 3)
```

Of course, it is straightforward to write a function that does what I want but I would prefer some efficient built-in or at least high-level approach. 
I am particularly interested in solutions for Python 3, where the `min`-function does not accept `None` as an argument.

Comment: Does `1. == 1.0`?

Comment: @pstatix Yes, it does.

Comment: Want to find the _first_ index? Meaning, can `1.` exist multiple times?

Comment: Returning the first index would be fine for resolving ambiguities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
min((v,i) for i,v in enumerate(l) if v is not None)
(1.0, 3) # (value, index)
```

Comment: This may well be the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably two part it:

```
m = min(x for x in l if x is not None)
s = (m, l.index(m)) # this will grab the first index
```

If you want to make the list a single pass + one liner solution:

```
midx, mval = min(enumerate(x if x is not None else float('inf') for x in l), key=lambda i: i[1])
```

The `enumerate()` piece produces an iterable like so:

```
0 2.0
1 inf
2 3.0
3 1.0
4 inf
5 2.0
6 inf
7 5.0
```

Then the `min()` gets called and uses the `enumerate()` return with `lambda` to check the values in the `i[1]` index (e.g. `2.0, inf, ..., 5.0`). Thus a final tuple is returned with only a single iteration using a generator from the original list to "filter and replace" the `NoneType` indices.

Comment: @vaultah Not sure of another native solution. It total its O(N) + O(N) = O(N)

Comment: As in my answer, I think `min` + `enumerate` should give a one-pass solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a conversion function and use this with `min`:

```
lst = [2., None, 3., 1., None, 2., None, 5.]

def converter(x):
    return x[1] if x[1] is not None else float('inf')

res = min(enumerate(lst), key=converter)[::-1]

(1.0, 3)
```

If you're happy using a 3rd party library, the equivalent in NumPy:

```
arr = np.array(lst).astype(float)
arr[np.isnan(arr)] = np.inf

res = arr.min(), arr.argmin()
```

Or, more efficiently, you can use `np.nanargmin`:

```
arg = np.nanargmin(arr)
minval = arr[arg]

res = minval, arg
```

Comment: If you see my post, does the same without the need to add a function to the namespace.

Comment: @pstatix, Sure, I upvoted yours, it works. But I think it's more readable to add a function to the namespace.

Comment: Fair enough, though personally, unless this list is massive, an O(N) solution as I originally put (and what yours and my updates are as well) is fine by breaking it into a very readable two liner. The fact that you iterate over the list twice makes no difference because it is O(N) regardless as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list).

Comment: @pstatix, Yep I get your O(n) point. I think what vaultah and I mean is the one-pass method will also work with a generator (not `list`-specific), while this is not possible with the 2-pass (unless you copy your generator and exhaust it twice, which is expensive).

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [2., None, 3., 1., None, 2., None, 5.]

idx = l.index(min(x for x in l if x is not None))

print(l[idx], idx) # get value, and idx
```

**Output**

```
1.0 3
```

Comment: sorry i change it `1.0 3`

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
l = [2., None, 3., 1., None, 2., None, 5.]
l = [(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(l) if v is not None]
print( sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0])[0] )
```

**Output:**

```
(1.0, 3)
```

Comment: Oh ok...sorry did not test that

Comment: @vaultah `l = [(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(l) if v is not None]` ?

Answer (score 0):

`value = min(l, key=lambda x: float('inf') if x is None else x)
index = l.index(value)`

Maybe include a check that value isn't inf if that is a concern (ie. the case where there are no numbers in l)

This method avoids constructing a new array internally by simply changing the way min compares values.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using `key` like so:

```
>>> import operator as op
>>> import itertools as it
>>> min(it.filterfalse(op.methodcaller('__contains__', None), zip(l, it.count())))
(1.0, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The most complex was to replace in a list, i think :

```
        import numpy as np

        l = [2., None, 3., 1., None, 2., None, 5.]

        #### function to replace in a list 
        def replaced(sequence, old, new):
            return (new if x == old else x for x in sequence)

        l=list(replaced(l,None,np.nan))

        #### numpy specific function
        position = np.nanargmin(l)
        value = l[position]

        print(position, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I prefer accepted answer.
A demo code where you can use NoneType :

```
lst = [2., None, 3., 1., None, 2., None, 5.]


    
def converter(x):
    NoneType = type(None)
    return x[1] if not isinstance(x[1], NoneType) else float('inf')
       
      
res = min(enumerate(lst), key=converter)[::-1]

print(res)
```

gives

```
(1.0, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

why the results should be (1., 3), after 1, 2 is following

```
l = [2., None, 3., 1., None, 2., None, 5.]

bar = map(float, [e for e in l if isinstance(e, float)])
print (min(float(i) for i in bar))
```