# How to find "maximum" value in a "List" and to extract the respective row data

Tags: python, list, max, row

arr = [E1,     E2,    E3,       E4,    E5,  E6]

E1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]

E2 = [ 10, 0.2, 23, 14, 85, 5 ]

E3 = [ 11, 21, 13, 14, 51,7 ]

E4 = [ 12, 22, 13, 24, 15,41 ]

E5 = [ 51, 26, 32, 41, 15, 65 ]

E6 = [ 11, 2, 13, 4, 15, 7 ]

max(E6) = 15

(row of the 15)

print 5, 85, 51, 15, 15, 15

Can someone please help me with this:

I have 6 lists. I want to find a maximum value in one column (one list) and to extract the respective row data (as described above).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the index of the returned max or min item using max()/min() on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have a list of list like this

```
arr = [[0, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3], [5, 4, 2, 0, 1, 3], [4, 1, 0, 3, 5, 2], [2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5], [1, 5, 2, 0, 3, 4], [2, 1, 4, 5, 3, 0]]
```

To get the row on which the 6th column value is max, first sort the array in reversed order, based on 6th column and the get the first element

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(arr, key=itemgetter(5), reverse=True)[0]
# [2, 1, 0, 3, 4, 5]
```