# Obtain the index of a list of dates that is the closest to a given date

Tags: python, date

I have the following `date`:

```
date=np.datetime64 (2019-12-15)
```

then I have a list of np.datetime64 dates:

```
['2018-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-04-12','2019-12-01']
```

I would like to obtain the `index` from the `list` which is closest to my date.

The desired output would be `3` which is the position of the list of dates closer to my date.

I am not able to provide an example given I dont know how to test my issue.

I can only think of an `assert.AlmostEqual` but I am not sure on how to reflect it on an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Express your list as a numpy array and just find the index of the smallest difference using `np.argmin`:

```py
import numpy as np

date = np.datetime64('2019-12-15')
array = np.array(['2018-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-04-12','2019-12-01'],
                 dtype=np.datetime64)

result = np.argmin(np.abs(array - date))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [datetime](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html) documentation, you can calculate timedeltas by simply subtracting the dates.

```
#Set date
date=np.datetime64 ('2019-12-15')


#Create list of strings holding date values
l = ['2018-01-01','2019-01-01','2019-04-12','2019-12-01']

#Convert strings to numpy dates 
l = [numpy.datetime64(x) for x in l]

#For each value in date list, subtract from start date. 
delta = [abs(x - date) for x in l]

#Set minimum index (see link below)
idx = np.argmin(d)
```

This will output `3`.

Min index code obtained from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825864/5763413)