# how to split array based on value in array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, split

Basically i have an array of data, and i want to split in into 2 based on the minima of the array. I tried a for loop, but it splits it based on the magnitude of the values, rather than, effectively, if its to the left or right of that value. I guess im looking for something effectively like the split module in numpy, but that returns 2 independent seperate arrays rather than an array with subarrays in it.

```
node1=[]
node2=[]
for i in profile_coarse:
    if i<7.2e-10: 
        node1.append(i)
    else:
        node2.append(i)
```

obviously because 7.2e-10 is the minima, all the values go to node2 and node1 remains an empty array. The minima is somewhere in the middle of my data array, and i want everything that comes before it to be stored in node1 and everything after in node2. i vaguely know what np.where is, but i cant seem to apply it correctly here. how can i alter the condition of the if loop such that it works?
Thanks so much for the help!

EDIT:
using the idea of the index of an array, i got here:

```
 node1=[]
 node2=[]
for index in enumerate(profile_coarse):
    if i<get_lowest_minima(profile_coarse)[0]:                        
        node1.append(i)
    else:
        node2.append(i)
print("array node1", node1, "array node2", node2)
```

which doesnt work - it fills the node1 array, and leaves node2 empty...i cant figure out why. teh get_lowest_minima(profile_coarse)[0] bit is an interger element of a tuple, and profile_coarse is the array of my data. help!

Comment: hint: you care about the *index* of an element, not its value. read about slicing

Comment: very fair point - did not properly understand hat that was before! heres what im trying to do with that - but its not working. any ideas?


edit: i put it in the question, since the formatting is much nicere there

Comment: @Adam.Er8 would really appreciate your help still! ive only just been able to pick up the project again today.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
split_index = data.index(min(data))
data1 = data[:split_index]
data2 = data[split_index+1:]
```

You could also find the `split_index` with:

```
split_index = min(range(len(data)), key=data.__getitem__)
```

For more details check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list) question.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to find the index of the minimum value and then split the array based on that index.

```py
import numpy as np


a = np.random.randint(0, 255, 10). # sample data [  9  33 155  48 196   3  96 185 112 104]

min_index = np.argmin(a)

node1 = a[:min_index]  # [  9  33 155  48 196]
node2 = a[min_index:]  # [  3  96 185 112 104]
```