# Find highest score and print

Tags: python, list

I'm doing a school assignment in Python and have made a "dart game" where you select the number of players and the number of throws each player gets. Points are given randomly.

I want to sum up each players score and announce a winner. I've gotten to the summing part, but can't figure out how to announce the correct winner. Now everyone is a winner which is nice, but not correct.

Any ideas on how I should solve this?

```
import random                                   
player = int(input("How many players? "))         
throws = int(input("How many throws per player? "))            
score_list = []

                                                
for i in range(player):                    
    player_score = []                           
    for j in range(throws):                
        score = random.randrange(1, 50)        
        player_score.append(score)             
    score_list.append(player_score)             
                                                
i = 0                                           
j = 0

for i in range(player):                                    
    print("Player " + str(i + 1) + " got these points: ")    
    for j in range(throws):
        print(str(score_list[i][j]))                             

i = 0
j = 0

for i in range(player):
    sum = 0
    biggest_sum = 0
    for j in range(throws):
        sum += score_list[i][j]
    print(f"Player {i+1} got {sum} points in total")
    if sum >= biggest_sum:
        biggest_sum = sum
        print(f"Player {i+1} got the most points and won!")
```

Comment: You need to not only remember the biggest sum, but also the player(number) that has it. Then print _after_ the loop is finished

Answer (score 0):

Some food for thought:

```
scores = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [5, 6, 0],
    [2, 4, 4]
]

max_score = max(scores, key=sum)
winning_player = scores.index(max_score) + 1

print(f"Player #{winning_player} is the winner, with {sum(max_score)} points!")
```

Output:

```
Player #2 is the winner, with 11 points!
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. Keeping the right index was a struggle for me but this was a good way to do it!

Comment: You're welcome. A side effect of this, however, is that if two players have identical scores (the score lists are identical, with the same values at the same indices), the player who appears first in the list will be selected as the winner.

Answer (score 0):

You may use list comprehension:

```
score_list = [[9, 4, 35], [2, 32, 45]]
sc1 = [sum(x) for x in score_list] #sum sub-list and get the maximum value of the resultant list        
print(f'Player {sc1.index(max(sc1))+1} wins with a score of {max(sc1)}')
```

Comment: Don't forget he also needs the index of the maximum row sum to know which player won... so it's basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2474015).