# How to count the length of an array from the beginning of the array up to the largest number numbers in the same array?

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
item_no = [5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 4, 2, 0]

max_no = max(item_no)

print(max_no)
print(len(item_no))
```

Expected output as follows:

```
max_no=8
```

Length from the beginning up to the `max_no` =  3

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2474238/5923139) gives you both the min value and min index.

Comment: `item_no.index(max(item_no))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to getting the index of the maximum value:

```
max_no = item_no.index(max(item_no))
```

or alternatively:

```
max_no = max(range(len(item_no)), key=item_no.__getitem__)
```

output: `3`