# How can I display something like "5 was rolled the most often (25 times)" at the bottom of this code?

Tags: python

As the question says, I need to display the most common dice roll and its frequency. It's a simulation and analysis question for school. I need the last line printed to read something like "x was rolled the most often (y times)"

```
from random import randint

print("Dice simulation and analysis program")
results = []
frequencies = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# Loop 100 times
for i in range (100):
    throw_result = randint(1,6) # store a random value between 1 and 6
    results.append(throw_result) # append each value to results

    # Start to build up a list of frequencies for each value thrown
    if throw_result == 1:
        frequencies[0] = frequencies[0] + 1
    elif throw_result == 2:
        frequencies[1] = frequencies[1] + 1
    elif throw_result == 3:
        frequencies[2] = frequencies[2] + 1
    elif throw_result == 4:
        frequencies[3] = frequencies[3] + 1
    elif throw_result == 5:
        frequencies[4] = frequencies[4] + 1
    elif throw_result == 6:
        frequencies[5] = frequencies[5] + 1

print()
# print("Results:", results)
print("Frequences:", frequencies)

print("Dice Frequency")
print("---- ---------")
print("1    ", frequencies[0])
print("2    ", frequencies[1])
print("3    ", frequencies[2])
print("4    ", frequencies[3])
print("5    ", frequencies[4])
print("6    ", frequencies[5])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the index of the returned max or min item using max()/min() on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list)

Comment: You could explore `collections.Counter` to simplify the code and logic.  then `counts.most_common(1)` will give you answer.

Answer (score 1):

`max` will give you the highest value in an iterable. We can use `index()` on the `frequencies` array to find the index of the highest element. These two together give you the information you need to print your statement.

```
most_rolls = max(frequencies)
print(f"{frequencies.index(most_rolls) + 1} was rolled the most often ({most_rolls} times)")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
max_ix = max(range(len(frequencies)), key= lambda x: frequencies[x])
print(f"{max_ix+1} was rolled the most often ({frequencies[max_ix]} times)")
```

Or easier way, you can use `numpy.argmax`

Answer (score 0):

You should really use

```
frequencies[i] += 1
```

instead of creating 6 different `if/else` statements.
And to print the final frequencies, use a `for` loop:

```
for i in range(6):
   print(str(i + 1) + "    ", frequencies[i])
```

Comment: Even simper is to use `Counter` in `collections` module. (it's also faster)

Comment: Sure, but it's probably not the best approach for a beginner in my opinion