# finding the index of max and min in an array

Tags: java

This is my code. I am using the bluej IDE.

```
    public class practice
    {
public int[] minMax(int[] num) {  
int smallest = num[0];
int largest = num[0];
int countsmall = 0;
int countlarge = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= num.length - 1; i++){
    if (num[i] < smallest) smallest = num[i];
    if (num[i] > largest) largest = num[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i <= num.length - 1; i++){
    if (num[i] != smallest) countsmall++;
    if (num[i] != largest) countlarge++;
}
int array[] = {countsmall,countlarge};
return array;
}
}
```

I am trying to find the minimum and maximum value in an array which I successfully did. After that,I am trying to find its index. I created a variable count, and then went through the array. If that item in the array does not equal the minimum or maximum value, count+= count. However, for some reason its not working. The code compiles but returns the wrong value. Keep in mind I am not allowed to use java libraries. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the index of the returned max or min item using max()/min() on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474015/getting-the-index-of-the-returned-max-or-min-item-using-max-min-on-a-list)

Comment: There is no need to count indices until you find a value that you found in a previous loop. Whenever you set `smallest` or `largest`, the value of `i` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want also indexes of biggest and smallest, why dont you do it in one loop? eg:

```
public class practice
{
    public int[] minMax(int[] num) {  
      int smallest = num[0];
      int largest = num[0];
      int countsmall = 0;
      int countlarge = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        if (num[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = num[i];
            countsmall=i;
        }
        if (num[i] > largest) {
            largest = num[i];
            countlarge=i;
        }
      }
    
      int array[] = {countsmall,countlarge};
      return array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Relating to the post above:for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
        if (num[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = num[i];
            countsmall = i;     Do you know why when I change int i = 1 or int i =2; it still returns the same index?

Comment: @blackpanther why it should return the same index? consider you have `{22,3,4,5}` now after changing to `i=1` it will never considerate `22`.It will be simply skipped and another largest number will be produced along with its index.