# How to get the index of a list value in Ansible?

Tags: list, ansible

The playbook that I am using is gathering Netapp data and then storing it in the list of dictionary. Thereafter, I am trying to take the required values out of the same list. Finally I am trying to get the `index` of `max` from the required `list(list_of_available_size)`. During this task I get an error.

Below is the playbook I am using.

```yaml
---
- hosts: exec-node
  collections:
    - netapp.ontap

  vars:
    list_of_available_size: []
    list_of_aggr_name: []
  vars_files:
    - secretvars.yaml

  tasks:
    - name: Gather aggregate info
      netapp.ontap.na_ontap_rest_info:
        hostname: "nas.foo.com"
        username: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        https: true
        fields:
          - 'space'
        validate_certs: false
        gather_subset:
          - storage/aggregates
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        aggrdetails: "{{ result['ontap_info']['storage/aggregates']['records'] }}"
    - debug: var=aggrdetails
    - name: Available size check in the aggregates
      loop: "{{ aggrdetails }}"
      set_fact:
        list_of_available_size: "{{ list_of_available_size+[item['space']['block_storage']['available']] | map('int') }}"
    - debug: var=list_of_available_size
    - name: aggregare listing
      loop: "{{ aggrdetails }}"
      set_fact:
        list_of_aggr_name: "{{ list_of_aggr_name+[item['name']] }}"
    - debug: var=list_of_aggr_name
    - name: Max available size aggr
      set_fact:
        max_size: "{{ list_of_available_size | max }}"
    - debug: var=max_size
    - name: index of max available size aggr
      set_fact:
        aggr_index_required: "{{ list_of_available_size | index(max_size) }}"
    - debug: var=aggr_index_required
```

Below is the error I get.

```yaml
TASK [Max available size aggr] **************************************************************************************
ok: [nas.foo.com]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [nas.foo.com] => {
    "max_size": "1491563708416"
}

TASK [index of max available size aggr] *****************************************************************************
fatal: [nas.foo.com]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: No filter named 'index'.. String: {{ list_of_available_size | index(max_size) }}"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
nas.foo.com : ok=10   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

[b00193@vmu81181 nas-ansible-netapp]$
```

Can someone please let me know how can I get the index of highest number from the list?

Comment: There is indeed no `index` filter. `.index()` is a method of a Python list, though, so, you should try `my_list.index(foo)` instead of `my_list | index(foo)`

Comment: I tried with the python syntax also. But I get below mentioned error now.
FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid valueor was: '1491906289664' is not in list\n\n

Comment: If you could make  a playbook people could run, include the data returned from your NAS statically, someone could probably help you parse the data structure pretty easily.

Comment: Hi @MattBlaha Below is the content of list wherein I am trying to find index of a specific value.

list_of_available_size: 
[1485972381696, 1491860144128]

& Below is that specif value I am trying to find index for in the above list. 
"max_size": "1491860144128"

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, or just `LIST | ansible.utils.index_of('eq', LIST | max)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe not terribly efficient, but if I'm following you, I think you really just want to get the index of the max value of a list of integers.

There are some modules you can install to do this, but to do this with just pure Ansible, this works and is easy to read:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    nums:
      - 37
      - 109
      - 302
      - 31
      - 100093

  tasks:

    - name: Get index of max value
      set_fact:
        idx: "{{ index }}"
      when: item == max | int 
      loop: "{{ nums }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: index
      vars:
        max: "{{ nums | max }}"

    - name: debug idx
      debug:
        msg: "{{ idx }}"
```

Note: This technically just gets the *first* value that contains that value, I gather that's what you want.

If you want to be much faster but get a little less pure Ansible, use Jinja like this:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    nums: "{{ range(0, 9830, 3) | list }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Get index of max value
      set_fact:
        idx: "{{ nums.index(nums | max) }}"

    - name: debug idx 
      debug:
        msg: "{{ idx }}"
```

Comment: "_This is maybe not terribly efficient_", indeed. Depending on the data type, the list length and the size of the elements it can become very slow. If there are only a few values, for rapid prototyping or as a fast and lazy approach I am using loops too quite frequently. Here, in this case, it can and should be avoided. But in any case it is a good example for `loop_control` and `index_var`.

Comment: Yes this code works well. Thank you Matt...

Comment: @U880D What makes it slow is less size of the data as just the length -- Ansible creates a task for each iteration, I'm pretty sure that's where most of the overhead is. But for just a few items, I'd still generally write it this way for the sake of most Ansible devs being the most comfortable with it. The happy medium is probably to drop to Jinja before bundling a filter plugin if someone wants to stick to just a playbook.

Answer (score 0):

> *How to get the index of a list value in Ansible? ... How can I get the index of highest number from the list?*

In addition to [the already given answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75568154/6771046)

> *There are some modules you can install to do this ...*

such are most probably already installed. A more efficient way without any loop and with just Ansible filters is the following minimal example

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    nums:
      - 37
      - 109
      - 302
      - 31
      - 100093

  tasks:

  - name: Show max value
    debug:
      msg: "{{ nums | max }}"

  - name: Show index of max value (count from zero)
    debug:
      msg: "{{ nums | ansible.utils.index_of('eq', nums | max) }}"
```

resulting into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show max value] *********************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '100093'

TASK [Show index of max value (count from zero)] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '4'
```

**Summary**

In short, the filter will not be

```yaml
index(LIST | max)
```

but instead

```yaml
LIST | ansible.utils.index_of('eq', LIST | max)
```

**Further Documentation**

- [Ansible.Utils](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/index.html)

  > *Ansible Collection with utilities to ease the management, manipulation, and validation of data within a playbook ... Supported ansible-core versions: 2.9.10 or newer*
- [Managing list variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables)
- [`index_of` filter – Find the indices of items in a list matching some criteria](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/utils/index_of_filter.html)

There is also a [Lookup plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html) available

- [`index_of` lookup – Find the indices of items in a list matching some criteria](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/utils/index_of_lookup.html)

---

**Further Research**

After looking up the former mentioned filter source of [Ansible.Utils](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.utils), [`plugins/plugin_utils/index_of.py`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.utils/blob/main/plugins/plugin_utils/index_of.py) and based on [Getting the index of the returned max or min item using max()/min() on a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825864/6771046), I've created a minimal example [Custom Filter Plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#developing-filter-plugins)

**`plugins/filter/index_max.py`**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'index_max': self.index_max,
        }

    def index_max(self, List):
        return max(range(len(List)), key=List.__getitem__)
```

which when called via

```yaml
  - name: Custom Filter Test
    debug:
      msg: "{{ nums | index_max }}"
```

also results into the requested output.

This might be useful if there are huge lists or bigger data sets.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    # Generate test data set with 32768 values
    nums: "{{ range(0, 98303, 3) | list }} "

  tasks:

  - name: Show index of max value (count from zero)
    debug:
      msg: "{{ nums | ansible.utils.index_of('eq', nums | max) }}"

  - name: Custom Filter Test
    debug:
      msg: "{{ nums | index_max }}"
```

Some runtime results

```yaml
TASK [Show index of max value (count from zero)] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '32767'

TASK [Custom Filter Test] ******************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '32767'

Show index of max value (count from zero) -------- 1.02s
Custom Filter Test ------------------------------- 0.44s
```

or from the loop example but with only a `/10` of values (`range(0, 9830, 3) | list`)

```yaml
TASK [Get index of max value] **************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=9828)

TASK [debug idx] ***************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: 3276

Get index of max value ------------------------- 159.17s
debug idx ---------------------------------------- 0.07s
```

---

Further good reading and resources regarding Custom Filter Plugins and apart  from the already linked Ansible `core.py` link is in example [`vbotka/ansible-plugins`](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins).